# Kusto query issue with timestamp column order

Tags: kql

I have a kusto query which has columns 'a','b', 'c','d' and 'timestamp'.

It basically is as

```
object
| serialize rn = row_number()
| project rn, a, b, c, d, timestamp
| project-reorder rn, timestamp
| order by timestamp desc
```

This returns output having timestamp as the first column which I do not want. Row number should be the first column followed by timestamp.

I have tried to order the query in multiple ways but still not able to get the desired output. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, haven't noticed until I read your post and I can verify this behavior.
Got it working as you need it by renaming the timestamp column:

```
object
| serialize rn = row_number()
| project rn, a, b, c, d, time1 = timestamp
| project-reorder rn, time1
| order by time1 desc
```

Comment: Did not think of renaming timestamp column :-0